# How to Store and retrieve the the correct Type of DerivedClass Pointer To/From Map of BaseClass Pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, smart-pointers

Hello i have question about Maps and Inheritance.
I have Map of BaseClass Pointer:

`std::map<int,std::shared_ptr<Game>> GamesByID;`

and inserted Derived Class Pointer into it like:

`GamesByID.insert(make_pair(ID,std::make_shared<ActionGame>(ID,Title,Metacritic,Recommendations,Price,lvl)));`

now i wanted to count how many ActionGame Pointer i had in my map with somthing like that

```
  for (auto& e : GamesByID)
        {
    if(typeid(e) == typeid(SurvivalGame)){
            ++count;
            
    }else{
        cout << typeid(e).name() << "  typeid" <<endl;
    }

}
```

But in the map ther are only BaseClass Pointer, now what is my mistake do i instert them wrong ?

Comment: Do you know what virtual methods are, how they work, and how to use them?

Comment: You could use `dynamic_cast`, although a lot of people would call that a code smell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map contains pointers of type "Game" nothing to do with derived class, the name to store a derived class with a pointer of base class is called polymorphism,
You will need a function to return something like a flag to get what type of class it is.
What I'm trying to say is that polymorphism will let you create a pointer variable with the type of the base class that can hold the address of a derived class the pointer itself in the map is not a derived class object

```
class baseClass
{
protected:
    string type = "baseClass";
public:
    string getClassType()
    {
        return this->type;
    }
}
class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
    derivedClass()
    {
        this->type = "derivedClass";
    }
}
```

Here I gave you an example where the base class has a `type` variable where you store the type and now if you check the type member of a `baseClass*` you will get a string telling you the type since both the variable and function to return the variable are in base class